# How can I get all the array elements from mongodb instead of first element creating piepline for python

Tags: python, mongodb, pipeline

```
{'$project': {
        '_id': 1,
        "tag": '$abc',
        "service": 1,
        "rec_id": 1,
        "valid": 1,
        "position": {'$switch': {
            'branches': [
                {
                    'case': {'$ne': ['$valid','no']},
                    'then': {'$first':{
                        '$filter': {
                            'input': '$positions',
                            'as': 'pc',
                            'cond': {"$eq": ["$$pc.deleted", False]}
                        }
                    }}
                },
                {
                    'case': {'$eq': ['$valid', 'no']},
                    'then': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$positions',0]}
                },
            ]
        }}
    }},
```

from the above code I am getting only the first element but I want all the elements inside it.

Comment: Can you add an example for your input data and the expected output?

Comment: looks like you use `$first` , that take only the first, can you remove it? maybe its small typing mistake